# Reasonable data-structure type for a Directed graph in Ocaml

Tags: data-structures, graph, ocaml, graph-theory

I want to use an adjacency list to represent a graph structure, I don't need my edges to be weighted.
I want to practice simple exercises like finding a cycle, BFS, DFS , adding remove edges... nothing fancy. (I could do it with Hashtables as well, but I need more `List` practice)

```
type 'a dgraph = DG of ('a * 'a list) list
```

My questions are :

1. Is this a reasonable representation for a DG ?
2. shouldn't these be a recursive type ? (somehow feels more natural)

I don't want to shoot myself in the foot and make a poorly designed `type` from the beginning, that will lead to a more complex implementation.

Example :

```
let g = 
    DG (
        [
            ('a', ['c'; 'd']);
            ('c', ['d']);
            ('b', ['a'; 'e']);
        ]
    )
```

*Note :*

I didn't find on http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html#Graphs the adjacency list representation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly good representation of a graph. You need to make sure the labels are unique. Also you have no distinction between the labels and other possible contents of the nodes.

With this structure, going from a label to the node with the label requires a search of the outer list. If your graphs get large, this is probably going to start taking too long. So you will need to construct an ancillary map from label to node. I have done this myself many times.

Another solution is to have node indices that are independent of the node contents. This also reduces the difficulty in dealing with duplicate labels. I'm working on graph problems right now and the structure is basically like this:

```
 type 'a mygraph = ('a * int list) array
```

The `'a` type represents the contents of a node, and array indices are used to link them together.

I've also worked with a structure that uses a hash table rather than an array. This works well when you have some unique identifier in your node type that you can use as an index. (Or you can use arbitrarily constructed indices.) The advantage of the hash table structure is that it's easier to modify the graph.

It might seem like your data structure should be recursive, but (in my opinion) this mixes up the graph and the *representation* of the graph. If you want your data structure to actually *be* a graph rather than just represent one, it does have to be recursive. Something like this:

```
type 'a rgraph = RG of 'a * 'a rgraph list
```

A data structure like this is almost impossible to work with in an eager language like OCaml. It's extremely difficult to construct the required values when they have cycles.

It can be done using `let rec`:

```
# let rec rg1 = RG (17, [rg1]);;
val rg1 : int rgraph = RG (17, [<cycle>])
```

However I've personally never seen "real world" code that works with a structure like this. Note that this use of `let rec` is marked as a language extension in the OCaml manual (Section 7.2, Recursive definitions of values).

You can make such a data structure more tractable by using references, something like this maybe:

```
type 'a rrgraph = RRG of 'a * 'a rrgraph list ref
```

Then you can create your nodes and link them together afterward. I have used structures like this in the past, but I felt I lost some of the nice guarantees of working with immutable data.

```
# let node1 = RRG (7, ref []);;
val node1 : int rrgraph = RRG (7, {contents = []})
# let node2 = RRG (8, ref []);;
val node2 : int rrgraph = RRG (8, {contents = []})
# let RRG (_, links) = node1 in links := [node2];;
- : unit = ()
# let RRG (_, links) = node2 in links := [node1];;
- : unit = ()
# node1;;
- : int rrgraph = RRG (7, {contents = [RRG (8, {contents = [<cycle>]})]})
```

An advantage of a representation like this is that you can freely create new nodes without needing to maintain a central table that contains all of them. And the garbage collector takes care of removing nodes that are no longer reachable.